# Ansible update authorized_keys file

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write a generic operation to keep the `authorized_keys` file up to date on all our servers. Basically, I want to keep list developers and specify what servers they are allowed to connect to.

Here's what I have...

`ssh.yaml`

```
  tasks:
    - name: 'provision dev-app servers with correct keys'
      authorized_key:
        user: 'deployment'
        key: '{{ item.key }}'
        comment: '{{ item.email }}'
        state: '{{ item.state }}'
      when: "('dev-app' in group_names) and ('dev-app' in item.servers or 'all' in item.servers)"
      with_items:
        - '{{ users }}'
```

`vars.yaml`

```
  - name: 'Jacob Haug'
    username: 'jacob'
    email: 'jacob@jacobhaug.com'
    key: "{{ lookup('file', 'permissions/keys/jacob.pub') }}"
    servers:
      - 'all'
    state: 'present'

  - name: 'Some Developer'
    username: 'developer'
    email: 'developer@example.com'
    key: "{{ lookup('file', 'permissions/keys/developer.pub') }}"
    servers:
      - 'dev-app'
      - 'dev-admin'
      - 'prd-app'
      - 'prd-admin'
      - 'prd-scraper'
    state: 'present'
```

This works perfectly. However, I want to remove any items that were added to the `authorized_keys` in some other way. According to the documentation for the authorized_keys module, I could use the `exclusive` parameter, however, that option isn't loop aware and would require me to pass all the keys in one single batch operation.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html

What would be a better way to do this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc you are pointing to in your question regarding the `exclusive` option

> Whether to remove all other non-specified keys from the authorized_keys file. **Multiple keys can be specified in a single key string value** by separating them by newlines.

What I would try: use `set_fact` with a loop to create a var with the desired content and in the next task use that var in the `authorized_keys` module with the `exclusive` option. Something like (to be fully tested and adapted):

```
tasks:
    - name: 'get keys to declare'
      set_fact:
        declare_keys: >-
          {{
            declare_keys | default([])
            +
            [item.key + ' ' + item.email])
          }}
      when:
        - "item.state == 'present'"
        - "'dev-app' in group_names"
        - "'dev-app' in item.servers or 'all' in item.servers"
      with_items:
        - '{{ users }}'

    - name: 'provision dev-app servers with correct keys'
      authorized_key:
        user: 'deployment'
        key: '{{ declare_keys.join("\n") }}'
        exclusive: yes
```

Comment: That's a nice approach, especially since it keeps everything idempotent. My last ditch effort was to just clear out the authorized_keys file. However, that makes the play not idempotent.

Comment: Since you are using `exclusive` I don't see the point of clearing the file before hand. You'll either put the exact same keys and no change will happen or the full content of the file will be replaced with the new calculated string containing all keys.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem as you and imho the only solution is to build one keyfile local and then distribute it to the destination server. I'm doing the following:

```
- name: Create authorized_keys file
  local_action: "shell cat {{ ssh_user_key_path }}/{{ item }} >>{{ authorized_keys  }}"
  check_mode: False
  changed_when: False
  loop:
    - user1
    - user2
    - user3

- name: Distribute authorized_keys file to servers
  authorized_key:
    user: kvbapp
    key: "{{ lookup('file', authorized_keys) }}"
    path: "~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    exclusive: True
    manage_dir: True

- name: remove local temporary authorized_keys file
  local_action:
    module: file
    state: absent
    path: '{{ authorized_keys }}'
  check_mode: False
  changed_when: False
  run_once: True
```

Answer (score 0):

The play below creates the list of dictionaries "*my_keys*" which can be used to configure exclusive "*authorized_key*".

```
- set_fact:
    my_hosts: "{{ my_hosts|default([]) + item.servers }}"
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  when: item.state == "present"
- set_fact:
    my_keys: "{{ my_keys|default({})|combine({item: users|json_query(my_query)}) }}"
  vars:
    my_query: "[?servers.contains(@, '{{ item }}')].{key: key, state: state}"
  loop: "{{ my_hosts|unique }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value|json_query('[?state==`present`].key') }}"
  loop: "{{ my_keys|dict2items }}"
```

gives:

```
"msg": "dev-app [u'permissions/keys/jacob.pub', u'permissions/keys/developer.pub']"
"msg": "all [u'permissions/keys/jacob.pub']"
"msg": "dev-admin [u'permissions/keys/developer.pub']"
```

with modified data for demonstration purpose
1) same server "dev-app" for both users
2) filename instead of a key

```
users:
  - name: 'Jacob Haug'
    username: 'jacob'
    email: 'jacob@jacobhaug.com'
    key: "permissions/keys/jacob.pub"
    servers:
      - 'all'
      - 'dev-app'
    state: 'present'
  - name: 'Some Developer'
    username: 'developer'
    email: 'developer@example.com'
    key: "permissions/keys/developer.pub"
    servers:
      - 'dev-app'
      - 'dev-admin'
    state: 'present'
```